# max of a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to find the maximum value in a scipy.sparse matrix.  The docs [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.max.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.max) say there is a .max method.  Oddly, however, this doesn't work for me:

```
>>> import scipy.sparse as sps 
>>> a = sps.csr_matrix((3,3))
>>> a[0,0] = 1
>>> a.max()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 393, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
AttributeError: max not found
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

(I am using scipy version 0.11.0)

Answer (score 1):

Some archeology in the [scipy docs website](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/) shows that method being introduced in scipy 13.0.

If you do not want to upgrade, you can get the maximum of the non-zero entries of your sparse matrix with `a.data.max()`.

If you want it to be the maximum considering the zeros as well, which is what the `.max()` method does, do something along the lines of:

```
m = a.data.max()
if m < 0 and a.nnz < a.shape[0]*a.shape[1]:
    m = 0
```